# search function using framework codeigniter, php

Tags: php, codeigniter

my problem is i whenever i input `fname` and `mname` i got an error from the database. i just want to search both of `fname` and `mname` in search field.

my `search` controller function

```
  public function search()
  {
    $li = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $id = $this->session->userdata('idnumber');
    if($li == TRUE)
    {
      $this->load->model('users_model');
      $this->load->helper('smiley');
      $this->load->library('table');
      $image_array = get_clickable_smileys('http://localhost/efg/images/smileys', 'status');
      $col_array = $this->table->make_columns($image_array, 8);
      $image_array2 = get_clickable_smileys('http://localhost/efg/images/smileys', 'status');
      $col_array2 = $this->table->make_columns($image_array2, 8);
      $this->data['smiley_table1'] = $this->table->generate($col_array);
      $this->data['smiley_tables'] = $this->table->generate($col_array2);           
      if($this->input->post())
      {
        $search = $this->input->post('search');
        $memb = $this->users_model->search($search);
        $usersearch =  $this->users_model->search($search);
        $grpsearch =  $this->users_model->searchgrp($search);
        redirect ('home/profile/'.$memb);
      }
    }
 }
```

**My `users_model` model**

```
 public function search($search)
 {
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('users');
   $this->db->like('username',$search);
   $this->db->or_like('fname',$search);
   $this->db->or_like('lname',$search);
   $this->db->or_like('mname',$search);
   $query = $this->db->get();
   foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
   {
      $memb = $row['idnumber'];
   }
   $error = 'There is no record for the one you searched. Please go Back.';
   $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE idnumber ='$memb'");
   $hehe = $query1->result_array();
   if($hehe==NULL)
   {
     echo $error; exit;  
   }
   else 
   {
    return $memb;
   }
 }
```

Comment: can you post your exact error?

Comment: Okay sir wait :)

Comment: I already posted it sir.

Comment: define `$memb` above `foreach ` loop

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: memb

Filename: models/users_model.php

Line Number: 185

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp\www\efg\application\models\users_model.php
Line: 185
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\wamp\www\efg\application\controllers\home.php
Line: 421
Function: search

File: C:\wamp\www\efg\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: where should I define it sir? In controller or model?

Comment: you should re-structure your model

Answer (score 1):

Always check the varibles using in condition are declared before the condition.
If it doesnt pass the condition what would be the output

```
        public function search($search)
         {
           $this->db->select('*');
           $this->db->from('users');
           $this->db->like('username',$search);
           $this->db->or_like('fname',$search);
           $this->db->or_like('lname',$search);
           $this->db->or_like('mname',$search);
           $query = $this->db->get();
           $memb = null;
           foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
           {
              $memb = $row['idnumber'];
           }
           $error = 'There is no record for the one you searched. Please go Back.';
           $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE idnumber =$memb");
           $hehe = $query1->result_array();
           if($hehe==NULL)
           {
             return $error;
           }
           else 
           {
            return $memb;
           }
         }
```

Comment: An error message will occur if the condition doesn't pass.

Comment: So we should always check both the scenario when we use any variable in conditions

Comment: I tried to input both `fname` and `mname` and the said error is not anymore displaying, but the "$error = 'There is no record for the one you searched. Please go Back.';" is the one that's displaying.

Comment: does and_like exist?

Comment: You were passing $memb in single quotes in query remove that

Comment: I can't understand :(

Comment: what exactly "does and_like exist? " is this?

Comment: bcoz i just want to search bot fname and mname in my search field. bcoz that error is keep on occuring.

Comment: for now, only username and fname and lname is working, all of these are single input

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the variables that youll be using in queries are set. Trap before executing queries.
Also, use Query Builder (Active Record) when you can.

```
public function search($search)
{
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('users');
   $this->db->like('username',$search);
   $this->db->or_like('fname',$search);
   $this->db->or_like('lname',$search);
   $this->db->or_like('mname',$search);
   $query = $this->db->get();

   $memb = '';
   if ($query->result_array() > 0) {
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
         $memb = $row['idnumber'];        
      }
      if ($memb) {

         $this->db->select("*");
         $this->db->where("idnumber", $memb);
         $query1 = $this->db->get("users");

         //$query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE idnumber ='$memb'");

         $hehe = $query1->result_array();
         return ($hehe) ? $memb : false;
      }
      return false;
   } 

  $error = 'There is no record for the one you searched. Please go Back.';
  return $error;
}
```